# отображение процесса

Tags: c#

К примеру софт делает замену в файле (Replace) как мне написать чтобы он отображал уже сделанные файлы и + через пробел проценты то есть в % -ах сколько он уже замены выполнил в файле с которым работает? Есть какие нибудь варианты?

Comment: Что именно вызывает у вас затруднение, как посчитать процент зная общее количество и скопированное количество?

Comment: используете консольное приложение?

Comment: Да, консольное приложение
я знаю сколько строк в каждом txt а их 158 штук и кол-ство 150 txt

Comment: Может быть вот это будет в помощь [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918768/progress-bar-in-console-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918768/progress-bar-in-console-application)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте адаптировать под себя вариант с [ProgressBar](https://gist.github.com/DanielSWolf/0ab6a96899cc5377bf54).
 Он выводит на консоль процент выполненной работы.

Использование класса

```
Console.Write("Performing some task... ");
using (var progress = new ProgressBar()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        progress.Report((double) i / 100); // процент выполненной работы
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

Comment: подчеркнул только ProgressBar

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду подчеркнул? вы добавили в свой проект класс ProgressBar?

Comment: Блин не подумал об этом я

Comment: А что такое в for написано "100" ? Я так понимаю что до 100% будет доходит каждый файл когда софт обработал его?

Comment: в функцию Report передается процент выполненной работы. Здесь для примера сделан цикл, который показывает процент выполненной работы от 0 до 1. Вы его адаптируете под себя, что он будет показывать.

Comment: Как через софт, запустить запустить (Start) код в другом софте, пусть запущенный софт проработает 2 сек, и закрыть его?